# Control panel items access for active directory users

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory

Active directory group policy have options to disable different things. My question is that how can i enable control panel items for certain users i.e. printer access / date time properties access.

I've windows server 2003. It does not show all the control panel its in GPO under User Configuration.
I just can view Add or Remove Programs, Display, Printers and Regional and Language Options.

Can you please a little brief that in which definitions should i put?

Answer (score 1):

I only have access to Svr 2008R2 but from meory the control panel setting to only allow cvertain icons is the same.

Go into the GPO you want to control this setting, expand User Configuration - Policies - Administrative Templates - Contorl Panel - And edit the values in Show Only Specified Contorl Panel Items.
Simply enable the setting, put in the one's you want the users to see and that should do it for you.

For Windows XP to only show Date and Time simply put datetime.cpl in the definitions.

Edit: it would also be worth setting the Always open All COntrol Panel Items when opening Control Panel flag to true so that it goes to classic view when opening CPL. Will look a lot neater.