# Set permissions for control panel settings

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a windows 2008 server i am setting up with active directory, but i cant seem to figure out how to restrict certain settings in the control panel for an account on a computer on the domain. I have searched google, but the did not seem to help.

Comment: You can do this with Group Policy.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/365346/control-panel-items-access-for-active-directory-users

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617167(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: This question as written is extremely vague.  There are thousands of various settings managed under your control panel, but you said 'certain settings'.  If there is something in particular you need to block you need to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Using the group policy editor under:  User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel.  There are quite a few options to hopefully accomplish what you want.